# Free function that gives a lexicographically bigger string each time

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am implementing a toy db, and I need a *free* function that gives me a lexicophgraically bigger string each time it's called. It's for naming segment files.

Let's assume I have a max of 1000 files, and I'd prefer if the string was less than 10 characters long.

Could someone give me the easiest example of such a function in python? I'd really like to be a free function as I don't want to introduce complexity with state.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you expect the function to provide different, deterministic results without having state?

Comment: Any requirements other than just that it's lexicographically bigger? Otherwise `def make_bigger(esio_trot): return esio_trot + 'teg reggib'` trivially fits your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

A function that returns a different value each time you call it will have to keep some sort of state. However, defining a generator makes that relatively simple to manage. Specifically, `itertools.count` will produce an infinite stream of increasing integers; you just need to produce a suitable string from each integer.

```
from itertools import count


next_label = map("{:010}".format, count()).__next__
```

Then

```
>>> next_label()
'0000000000'
>>> next_label()
'0000000001'
>>> next_label()
'0000000002'
```

and so on, for as many times as you need to call `next_label`.